# Calculate total date ranges with or without gaps

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, date, math

I am trying to obtain the total years of different date ranges.
This is my code:

```js
function calculate(dates) {
  let total = 0;
  let previousStartYear;
  let previousEndYear;

  dates.forEach(date => {
    let endYear = new Date(date.EndingDate).getFullYear();
    let startYear = new Date(date.StartDate).getFullYear();

    if (previousStartYear && endYear > previousStartYear) {
      total += (endYear - startYear) - (endYear - previousStartYear);
      if (previousEndYear && endYear > previousEndYear) {
        total += (endYear - previousEndYear);
      }
    } else {
      total += endYear - startYear;
    }
    previousStartYear = startYear;
    previousEndYear = endYear;
  })
  return total;
}

// Eample 1
let x1 = calculate([{
    StartDate: '2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    EndingDate: '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    StartDate: '2006-03-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    EndingDate: '2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    StartDate: '2005-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    EndingDate: '2015-11-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    StartDate: '2002-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    EndingDate: '2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  }, ,
  {
    StartDate: '2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    EndingDate: '2008-11-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  }
])

console.log('Example 1: ' + x1);

let x2 = calculate([ //2
  {
    StartDate: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    EndingDate: '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    StartDate: '2017-03-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    EndingDate: '2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    StartDate: '2007-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    EndingDate: '2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  }
]);

console.log('Example 2: ' + x2)
```

The first example returns 22, while the second example returns the correct total: 13

Expected result should be able to calculate the ranges even with gaps such as:

2010 - 2011

2009 - 2011 - gap

2005 - 2007 - gap

2004 - 2008

I know I missed many conditions and calculations and I'm not sure if I handled the years between a range correctly.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Im not sure if I understood what you want correctly, but one way to do it is to get the lowest year of startDates, and then the highest year of endDates, and then just to highestEnd - lowestStart.

Comment: If all you care about is the year, then don't bother with Date objects. The year is just `date.EndingDate.split(/\D/)[0]`. If your timezone is west of Greenwich, then '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' will return a local year of 2018, which will affect results where the other part of the range is not 1 Jan.

Comment: @IWHKYB Thanks for the response. highestEnd - lowestStart would disregard the gaps

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems messed up, there's too much going on to provide a full analysis but here's a couple of issues:

```
previousStartYear = startYear;
```

it seems to me that should only be assigned if *startYear* is less than *prevoiusStartYear*, or *previousStartYear* hasn't been initialised. Same for `previousEndYear = endYear`.

Also '2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' will be parsed as UTC, so for users with a negative timezone offset, `new Date('2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z').getFullYear()` will return 2007, whereas any other date in the year will return 2008. You could fix that with `getUTCFullYear()`, but that might have other consequences.

If you just want to get the range from the earliest start year to the latest end year, then just get the earliest start year and subtract it from the latest end year, e.g.

```js
function calculate(data) {
  let o = {};
  data.forEach(obj => {
    // Don't bother with Dates, just get the year from the string
    let start = obj.StartDate.substr(0,4);
    let end = obj.EndingDate.substr(0,4);

    // Initialise o.start and o.end if not already done
    if (!o.start) {
      o.start = start;
      o.end = end;

    // Update values if start earlier or end later
    } else {
      if (start < o.start) o.start = start;
      if (end > o.end) o.end = end;
    }
  });

  // Get difference
  return o.end - o.start;
}


let data1 = [
  {StartDate: '2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
   EndingDate: '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {StartDate: '2006-03-01T00:00:00.000Z',
   EndingDate: '2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {StartDate: '2005-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
   EndingDate: '2015-11-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {StartDate: '2002-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
   EndingDate: '2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {StartDate: '2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
   EndingDate: '2008-11-01T00:00:00.000Z'}
];

console.log(calculate(data1)); // 15

let data2 = [
  {StartDate: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
   EndingDate: '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {StartDate: '2017-03-01T00:00:00.000Z',
   EndingDate: '2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {StartDate: '2007-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
   EndingDate: '2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z'}
];

console.log(calculate(data2)); // 13
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @RobG ! I tried adding this to in the else block to handle the gaps:

`if (end < o.start) {
        gap += o.start - end;
      }
      if (start < o.start) o.start = start;
      if (end > o.end) o.end = end;`

and then subtract the total gaps to the difference
`return (o.end - o.start) - gap;`

Although it works well with the given example on the question (the one with gaps), it subtracts 1 on the total of data2, making it 12. Could you help me point out what I missed? Thank you so much